# NSDictionary and NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have arrays of names and images like below

```
NSArray *names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"naveen", @"kumar",nil];
NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"], nil];
```

I want to create a dictionary in the following format

```
list:
  item 0 : naveen
       1.jpg
  item 1: kumar
       2.jpg
```

How can i create this one? Please?

Comment: I don't understand your format. Can you write it in JSON?

Comment: @Naveen: do you want "item 1" as as key, `Kumar` and `2.jpg` as values?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=ANc&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&q=simple+plist&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.bmk&biw=1202&bih=573&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=W8ZKUae5IYesrAfr4YGQBg#imgrc=jZoy6pXpdEpf0M%3A%3BVl3xb9zwub3DfM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fi.stack.imgur.com%252Fz0fAm.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fstackoverflow.com%252Fquestions%252F13616206%252Fcopying-objects-from-plist-file-to-another-plist-file%3B438%3B261       check link , instead of greenday i need item0   like tht

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do like this :

```
NSMutableDictionary *nameImageDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
for (NSInteger i=0; i<names.count; i++) {
    NSArray *array=@[names[i],images[i]];
    //or in older compiler 4.3 and below
    //NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[names objectAtIndex:i],[images objectAtIndex:i], nil];
    [nameImageDict setObject:array forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item %d",i]];
}
```

for key item 0: it will have an array. The array contains name and image.

Comment: what is this NSArray *array=@[names[i],images[i]];  ?

Comment: check my edit in answer. And see here http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: i think it will work ..i didnt check yet because my another function is not working "segment control in toolbar" programetical implementation..do u know that?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:images andKeys:names];
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
NSDictionary * list = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:images forKeys:names];
```

Comment: This is funny! We both wrote the same at the same time.

Comment: You beat me with a few seconds I suppose :)

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=ANc&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&q=simple+plist&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.bmk&biw=1202&bih=573&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=W8ZKUae5IYesrAfr4YGQBg#imgrc=jZoy6pXpdEpf0M%3A%3BVl3xb9zwub3DfM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fi.stack.imgur.com%252Fz0fAm.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fstackoverflow.com%252Fquestions%252F13616206%252Fcopying-objects-from-plist-file-to-another-plist-file%3B438%3B261      check that link  ,,in that greenday i need "item0"  2pac i need "item1"   like that

Comment: in that link instead of greenday in dictionary i need it as "item0" like that bro